# Returning a proper response for post request in Django

Tags: django, jquery

```
<form id="login_frm" method="post" action = "/login/user_auth/"> 
    <fieldset> 
    <legend>Login:</legend> 
        <label for="id_email">Email</label> 
        <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email" /> 

        <label for="id_password">Password</label> 
        <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /> 

    </fieldset> 
    <input name = "login" type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form> 


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login_frm').submit(function() {
            var $form = $(this);
            $.post('/login/user_auth/' , form.serialize(), function(data) {
               // alert ("function");
        alert (data);
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Django View:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # perform all logic / and db access
    data = "hello"
    return HttpResponse(data)
    # return HttpResponse ('success.html')
```

I have been stuck on this all afternoon.

1. When I return `data` as my response, for some reason, the browser displays "Hello" by loading a blank webpage with just "Hello" written on it; in the JavaScript function above, `alert (data);` is never called (I cannot understand why).
2. I am unable to render the success.html. I believe that if I write render_to_response inside the HttpResponse, I will solve this problem. However I think making point 1 work is a first priority.

**Goal**

After the post, I would like to capture the returned response from the server (whether it is just the "hello" message, or a webpage that displays a success message- stored in "success.html") and display it in place of the `login_frm` without having the browser refresh a new webpage.

Comment: Instead of "hello" in a plain page, what where you expecting to get returned when calling [data = "hello" return HttpResponse(data)]? Maybe instead of sending a new HttpResponse object you should alter an existing one? (My Django skills are real dusty so excuse me if this is a useless comment)

Comment: I don't quite understand your question: You are explicitly returning a response with just "hello" in it, so why do you expect the HTML and JavaScript to be loaded?

Comment: @AntiDog, I just do not expect the webpage to be refreshed, rather, as a post method, the result should be returned and the line alert (data) should be executed in th javascript function. Yuji's solution fixed it, it was an error in the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. `form` is undefined (you defined it as $form) and changing to `$form` fixed the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login_frm').submit(function() {
        var $form = $(this);
        $.post('/login/user_auth/' , $form.serialize(), function(data) {
           // alert ("function");
           alert (data);
       });
    return false;
    });
});
```

You might want to use something like `event.preventDefault()` so that future errors are not hidden from you like this. `$('form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); .....})`

Comment: thx, that's exactly it!! can't believe the headache this gave me. Quick Question: when there is an error in the javascript code (like here with an undefined variable), I have to wait until runtime in order to catch the error?

Comment: Unfortunately, if a function raises an error before being able to return false (overriding the submit event), the form will act as it's supposed to: submit to URL. Think about it this way: you have JavaScript overriding default form functionality. What happens when that javascript breaks? It never overrides the submit event.